# Unity Rigidbody2d.addforce wont change direction after force is applied

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, multiplayer

Having an issue where a 2D game (space) Im trying to move the player around using RB2D with addforce.  Seems that I can choose two directions at a time.  If I press down the player goes down but when pressing up it wont go up but will stop. Same with Left/Right.  Gravity is set to 0.  Both objects have a rigidbody2d and I require dynamic in order to allow for "bouncing" and other physics in game.

- Always present object (movement script)

  - Player Sprite (sprite)

**I want player to be able to move up,down,left,right.  Im really ok with it having a slowing effect but not required.  (If you let go of keys it slows down due to friction)**
[image]

My player is set to a tiered format as this is multiplayer and parent object always is in game.

I have tried the following
-Interchanging Dynamic + Kinematic on both or one on each.
-Adding force, transform, velocity, etc.
-Adjusted friction, drag , etc.
-Checked debug x/y forces are being applied in game but player wont move in opposite direction after first movement.

I have uploaded the files to [github here.](https://github.com/snub-fighter/SpaceCats)

#### Player Movement

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class PlayerUnit : NetworkBehaviour {
    //float speed = .5F;
    float rotationSpeed = 50.0F;

    float xMin;
    float xMax;
    float yMin;
    float yMax;
    // configuration parameters
    [Header("Player")]
    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed = .5f;
    [SerializeField] float padding = 1f;
    [SerializeField] int health = 200;
    [SerializeField] AudioClip deathSound;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float deathSoundVolume = 0.75f;
    [SerializeField] AudioClip shootSound;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float shootSoundVolume = 0.25f;

    Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start () {
       rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }


    void Update () {
        
        if( hasAuthority == false )
        {
            return;
        }
        if ( Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) )
        {
            this.transform.Translate( 0, 1, 0 );
        }     
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (true)
        {
            float leftright = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            float updown = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            float xForce = leftright * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            float yForce = updown * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            Vector2 force = new Vector2(xForce, yForce);

            rb.AddForce(force);
            Debug.Log("xForce : " + xForce + "      yForce : " + yForce);

            //float leftright = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
            //float updown = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed;
            ////rb.MovePosition(rb.position + new Vector2(1, 0) * leftright);
            //rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (transform.right * leftright + transform.up * updown) * moveSpeed);

            //rb.MovePosition(rb.position + new Vector2(0, 1) * updown);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, you just need to remove the `Rigidbody2D` on the child of `PlayerParentObject`. The only `Rigidbody2D` on the player should be on the same gameobject as the `Player Unit` script.

Comment: I rebuilt the whole thing from scratch (not code just project)  and its working now.